# Rails, cant get update to work with cocoon when removing attribute "undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cocoon-gem

I am wondering if someone could tell me why I am getting this error "undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass". This happens when I remove a picture with cocoon and try update. The method works fine for adding pictures to the edited gallery but I am getting this error when removing and updating. I tried using `unless @pictures.blank? end` I am assuming the problem is when cocoon removes the picture but I am not sure what to do from there. the server error is,

```
Started PATCH "/galleries/41" for ::1 at 2017-05-07 16:03:02 +1000
Processing by GalleriesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cG1UXCvODhYzqqAr++EAn8GvMVk7+t/eASkzDDOoPmJfw3l6ax/F2xXMhvs7FcrJ3LOuTd0sks5+2fb86kQv0Q==", "gallery"=>{"name"=>"Hellooo", "cover"=>"123456", "pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"47"}, "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"48"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Gallery", "id"=>"41"}
  Gallery Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 41], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: pictures_attributes
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
...
```

Perhaps if someone could explain this to me would be great!

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@gallery, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cover %>
    <%= f.text_field :cover %>
  </div>
  <div id="pictures">
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |pic| %>
    <%= render 'picture_fields', f: pic %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add picture', f, :pictures %>
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_picture_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, multiple: true, name: "pictures[picture][]" %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove picture", f %>
  </div>
</div>
```

GalleriesController

```
def update
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
       params[:pictures][:picture].each do |pic|
       @pictures = @gallery.pictures.create!(picture: pic)
      end
      flash[:success] = "Gallery Updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**Edit: Added gallery_params**

```
def gallery_params
   params.require(:gallery).permit(:id, :name, :user_id, :cover, picture_attributes: [:id, :gallery_id, :picture, :_destroy])
  end
```

**EDIT: Added create action and server log using cocoon**

```
 def create
    @user = User.first
    @gallery = @user.galleries.build(gallery_params)
    if @gallery.save       
       flash[:success] = "Picture created!"
       redirect_to root_url
    else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

server log

```
Started POST "/galleries" for ::1 at 2017-05-10 13:18:43 +1000
Processing by GalleriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XU3z2jMdbselPJZ2SdZdGPwiAebiPznt8GWRqmbv8LM/MIxO+sNo1z2NTaDQ3nJNm0qaBJ66ny5254MPpHZaQQ==", "gallery"=>{"name"=>"Hello", "cover"=>"123456", "pictures_attributes"=>{"1494386318553"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xac59228 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Lee/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170510-7596-16xlrir.jpg>, @original_filename="Skateboard 1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[pictures_attributes][1494386318553][picture]\"; filename=\"Skateboard 1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1494386321001"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xac59150 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Lee/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170510-7596-jxo0st.jpg>, @original_filename="Skateboard 2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[pictures_attributes][1494386321001][picture]\"; filename=\"Skateboard 2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Gallery"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering galleries/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered galleries/_picture_fields.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered galleries/_picture_fields.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered galleries/_picture_fields.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered galleries/_form.html.erb (42.0ms)
  Rendered galleries/new.html.erb within layouts/application (58.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 157ms (Views: 139.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error that says what line it is on?

Comment: yes on the line `params[:pictures][:picture].each do |pic|` in the controller. That is the line fileds_for takes in the parameters from the name in the _picture_fields partial. Obviously the array the pictures are sent in as is causing the error I am just unsure as to why as I am using some tutorials and my knowledge is limited on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm. Confused. There is no `params[:pictures]` so that is obviously `nil` (check the log you posted at the top). So that is causing the error. If you are looking for the pictures posted, you should refer to `params[:pictures_attributes]`, but not even sure what you are trying to do there: create an empty picture (again?) for each posted pictures? The pictures are saved by doing the `gallery.update(gallery_params)`.

Note: iterating over the posted params is imho definitely wrong, because if one is deleted, it will still be posted with the nested parameter `_destroy` set to true, so it can be deleted correctly from the database, or if a picture already existed, it will also be posted again (and not saved, since it already exists).

[EDIT] Add short solution:

- use `f.fields_for :pictures` in your view: this will iterate over the existing pictures a gallery has, and will allow to delete/edit existing, and add new pictures to a gallery
- fix your `gallery_params` and allow `pictures_attributes` (instead of the singular form)(otherwise nothing is saved)
- in your controller just write `@gallery.update_attributes(gallery_params)` and do not iterate over `params[:pictures]` at all (remove that part) and it should just work (because the `update_attributes` will already have done this, at least if you want to iterate manually use `pictures_attributes`)

Comment: The `params[:pictures][:picture].each do |pic|` line is to handle the multiple file select for each single field. I am confused also because in my standard form I need to explicitly use `<%= f.fields_for @gallery.pictures do |pic| %>` to get the file_field to show up, but if I do this with  `<%= link_to_remove_association "remove picture", f %>` I get a error on that line `undefined method `new_record?' #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` Maybe you can help with this?

Comment: I must let you know I am going through 3 models, A user has many galleries and a gallery has many pictures, but @gallery.pictures has to be mentioned to get the fields to show up using file_field without using cocoon and rendering a partial. I cant really understand it so I will create a app without the user model and only a gallery having many pictures..

Comment: The error you now mention is generally caused when you do `fields_for` instead of `f.fields_for` (see https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/173). The three levels should not make a difference. If you are using nested-fields you do not have to handle the different pictures manually, rails will do it for you.

Comment: Exactly, and I have seen examples of this using cocoon on github. I wanted to just use cocoon without multiple single field upload but when I do all I get is rollback transaction after User load, it will not insert into galleries and pictures column. The parameters come in fine, Can I post the server log and my create action just to check? This is what happens when I try create a gallery using cocoon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `save` fails before anything is actually written to the database, so this means imho that some validation is failing. Check them. Also in rails 5:  the `belongs_to` relation is now by default required, so you should add `inverse_of` to the `has_many` for it to save correctly.

Comment: Your gonna shoot me for this and maybe yourself, but the real reason things wern't working is because there is a error in the _form partial. Reading over your docs it says **partials to be properly wrapped with elements.** Where I did not. You can either add an update to your answer and I will keep it right or answer my own question?

Comment: Afaik the partial as shown here is properly wrapped, the wrapping is only relevant for deleting answers, not saving them, but i am very happy you found a working solution. You should do as you see fit, it is your question (and answer).

Comment: Ahh well yeah, once I put the `<div id="pictures">` end tag to wrap the `<div class="links">` tag then everything worked great, as you showed on guthub. Ill leave things as is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `gallery_params` method is not permitting your pictures_attributes.  You didn't post that code but I noticed in the error log `Unpermitted parameter: pictures_attributes` which means that your strong parameters(the gallery_params method) is filtering those parameters out.

Basically the whole point of the strong parameters is to make sure that you only pass through keys that you actually want to get passed through.  So your controller is like "Nobody told me I am supposed to accecpt picture_attributes so I won't allow them through."  Then your code is expecting there to be a picture object in the pictures array, but the pictures array doesn't have the picture object causing an error.

Can you post the code for gallery params?  Can you also post the contents of params?  Full disclosure: I don't really know rails 5 so there could be some other stuff going on.

Comment: I added that to the bottom of my question. The params are posted above in the server error coming in from the form. I should say this is when there are still pictures being sent through and says ` "pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=>`  Everything works fine creating but updating is a no go.

Comment: I see in my gallery_params, I have `picture` not `pictures` attributes, but I change it to pictures and for instance I cant create a gallery it rollsback transaction..

Comment: Now what is your error?  I would also tag a ! on the end of update until you figure out your issue.

Comment: Well, if I dont use cocoon because cocoon only works with a symbol, I can not pass in @gallery.pictures to fields_for, I have to use `:pictures`, everything works fine, so I have to figure out why I can not pass in `@gallery.pictures` to cocoon. Rails complains `undefined method `new_record?' for#<Picture::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0xc0c5958>` when its just `f.file_field :picture, multiple: true, name: "pictures[picture][]" %>` and no partial it works fine.